# Getting `render` call to return null when using Enzyme.mount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

### Question

Does anyone know of an acceptable way to get a mounted component to return `null` (or something similar) when using `Enzyme.mount`?

### Use case

I have a component that is wrapped in *n* higher-order components. I would like to actually `mount` the component instead of `shallow` because I would like to test that `componentDidMount` called something as expected.

My mount function/test goes something like this:

```
const component = <ApplicationsShowRoute />;
const { store } = mountSetup(component);
expect(store.getActions()).toEqual([ { type: 'API_REQUEST' } ]);
```

When I mount this, I'd prefer not have to worry about what's being rendered (errors in child components, etc).

### Code

```
export class ApplicationsShowRouteRaw extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const { uuid } = this.props.match.params;

    this.props.fetchShowRoute(uuid);
  }

  props: Props

  render() {
    const { application, match } = this.props;

    return isEmpty(application) || application.Uuid !== match.params.uuid ? (
      <FullPageLoader />
    ) : (
      <ApplicationsShow
        application={application}
      />
    );
  }
}

export const mapStateToProps = (state: Object) => ({
  application: getShowRoute(state),
});

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Function) => ({
  fetchShowRoute: (uuid: string) => dispatch(fetchShowRoute(uuid)),
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(ApplicationsShowRouteRaw);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `shallow` with [lifecycleExperimental](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md#shallownode-options--shallowwrapper) option set to `true` if you want shallow rendering with all lifecycle methods.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Now I can just target the raw component, and pass in `jest.fn` as a prop as opposed to having to `jest.mock` imports.